# Can i append a div which includes ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, append

i am trying to append a `div` to another `div`. But this `div` which i will append has a `ng-repeat` (AngularJS).

my html code looks like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and this is my jquery/angularjs function:

```
$('#content').append('<div ng-repeat="article in articles"><p>{{article.title}}</p></div>);
```

is it possible to run the `ng-repeat` after I append it?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Try running a $scope.$digest(); after you've appended.

Comment: Don't use angular and jquery like this. If you're using angular, then the content should exist in the HTML code already, but just be hidden with `ng-if` - it should not be appended there separately. If you're using jquery, then use jquery.each instead of ng-repeat. You're making your code unnecessarily complex if you try to use the separate philosophies of angular and jquery together.

Comment: sorry $scope.$digest() cant help me... i tried it but nothing happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to re-compile the DOM after appending new elements in the div

Your HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Step 1: Create HTML to be appended

```
 var articleHTML= angular.element('<div ng-repeat="article in articles"><p>{{article.title}}</p></div>');
```

Step 2: compile the template

```
var compileAppendedArticleHTML= $compile(articleHTML);
```

Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.

```
var element = compileAppendedArticleHTML($scope);
```

Step 4: Append to DOM

```
$("#content").append(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

This link may be helpful for you

> http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2014/08/append-or-prepend-html-to-div-using.html#.WJMS_qLhXIU

Comment: thanks but i think this it the same like $().append
i tried this solution but nothing happens